# Delphi/C++Builder: Float transparent image over form content

Tags: delphi, png, c++builder

I'd like to show a transparent PNG image at the top right corner of a form. The form content under it will change, depending on what features the user selects, so different components will be under the image at different times.

I'll use it as a 'watermark' shown while running in trial mode.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Watermarks are "under content", not on top of it... so do you really want the image be on top of the controls or do you want to use it as a background?

Comment: More details needed. First thought is just to put a `TImage` on the form and put your controls over the top. But it depends on what controls you have. If your client area is filled with a memo, say, then that's no good. How about a screenshot of the app.

Comment: Yes, I want it on top of it, because some of the controls are client-aligned document viewer controls for example. They don't support background images and takes up the entire form space, which is why I'm looking for a "always on top" transparent form/PNG solution.

Comment: You are going to need to alpha blend over the top at the end of the paint cycle.

Comment: Do you know of any examples showing how to do that?

Comment: The API function is called `AlphaBlend`.